# Call global @ControllerAdvice method from controller @ExceptionHandler method

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to handle exceptions in a controller using @ExceptionHandler and then rethrow that exception so a @ControllerAdvice can handle it?

I am trying to do it but when I rethrow the exception it doesn't reach the ControllerAdvice.

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {


  @GetMapping
  public Something getSomething() {
   ...
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public void handleException(Exception e) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Log!");
    throw e;
  }
```

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<...> handleException(Exception exception) {
   // Not working
   ...
  }
```

Some more context (hopefully you can give me some different ideas on implementing this):

Today our application has a GlobalExceptionHandler (annotated with RestControllerAdvice) that handles exceptions.

Now, we have a new business demand that 2 particular endpoints we have must now log some additional info like "endpoint GET /something got this error".

Any kind of exception must be logged, I need to log which particular endpoint it happened and I need to keep the global handler in place as it is responsible for creating the error responses.

One way to solve this would be to change each method on the global handler to inject the current request, retrieve the url from it, check a particular configuration if I need to log for that endpoint and log it, but it feels wrong adding this behaviour to all handler methods.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the aspect of AOP and wrap your request with catch an any exceptions?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RequestWrapperAspect {

 @Around("(@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping) || " +
            "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping) || " +
            "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping) || " +
            "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping) || " +
            "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping) || " +
            "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping)) && execution(public * *(..))")
    public Object wrapRequest(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //whatever you need to do
            throw e;
        }
}
```